# Java Mysterious NullPointerException

Tags: java

So I've got a bit of a mystery on my hands.  I'm passing some parameters into a method but the method never executes.  I've checked to make sure that none of the parameters themselves are null.  It doesn't even execute the first line in the method (a simple `System.out.println()`).  Any idea what the problem could be?

Here's the method under review:

```
public static void passedTest(String title, String startPhase, String endPhase,
            String startTime, String endTime, long startMilli, long endMilli, String testNum) {
        System.out.println("PASSED");
        endMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalLength += (endMilli - startMilli);
        passedCount++;
        try {
            out.newLine();
            out.write("Test Case " + testNum);
            out.newLine();
            out.newLine();
            out.write(title + " --- " + startPhase.toUpperCase() + " to "
                    + endPhase.toUpperCase());
            out.newLine();
            out.write("PASSED");
            out.newLine();
            out.write("__________________________________________");
            out.newLine();
            out.write("");
            out.newLine();
            out.write("\tSTARTED:  " + startTime);
            out.newLine();
            out.write("\tENDED:    " + endTime);
            out.newLine();
            out.write("\tDURATION: " + timeConverter(endMilli - startMilli));
            out.newLine();
            out.write("");
            out.newLine();
            out.write("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            out.newLine();
            out.write("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            out.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, show some of your code.

Comment: Please include the content of the method and the stacktrace...you know..the basics..

Comment: This is like trying to find Waldo, in a library with thousands of books, while blinded. EDIT: thank you for the code!

Comment: 1.) Error messages are fantastic, read them or show us if you can't figure it out 2.) If you are calling a function and it is seeming never called, _maybe it wasn't called_ so try investigating the calling code

Comment: The method was definitely called.  I've gone through the debugger and it gets TO the method, but nothing happens.

Comment: `out` is a private static BufferedWriter.  I've used this exact same method in other packages and it works without flaw.

Comment: Please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Take a copy of your current project, then hack it down until either you've got a short but complete program, or you've found the problem.

Comment: Here is the line: `public static BufferedWriter out = MasterClass.buff;` and MasterClass.buff is initialized like this: `buff = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);` and `fileWriter` is initialized like this (surrounded by a try/catch block): `fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);`

Comment: @JackRadcliffe, I just realized, why are you posting code for a method that never executes?

Comment: @JackRadcliffe, your own words - " into a method but the method never executes".

Comment: @jsn I meant that I call it, but it doesn't run.  Sorry for the complication.

Comment: can we see the code that calls passedTest?

Comment: @JackRadcliffe, I do not see a starting brace for that method. Does it even compile?

Comment: @jsn, look all the way to the right.

Comment: @JackRadcliffe, make sure you do not have two methods that have similar names (and you are calling the wrong one) or ones with similar signatures.

Comment: @jsn, see my comment on Andreas_D's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the first line in the method isn't executed, then the method simply doesn't get called. There is a chance, that *it is* actually executed and `System.out` has been redirected so that it doesn't print to the console but to somewhere else.

Take a debugger, set a breakpoint on all lines of code that call *this* method in your opinion  , debug and step into the method. Maybe you end up somewhere else...

Comment: Well you've spotted the problem.  It goes to the same method in a different package (under the same Java Project).  I'm not seeing any reason why this should happen though... Any suggestions?

Comment: And I have verified that the classes I'm working for are in the correct packages.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally imported the *wrong* class to call the static method. Double check your imports section, especially for static imports and imports with wildcards... that's a quite common "bug" ;)

Comment: And you've done it again.  For some reason it had put up there `import NOC_IM.UniversalVariables;` (the other package's version of the class).  I've never seen that happen before!  Thank you!